# Setting height for two ggplot graphs, plot side by side with plot_grid()

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have two ggplot graphs. When plot individually in Markdown, they have the right aspect ratio. When plot them side by side with *plot_grid()*, they look vertically stretched.

I just need show them side by side, but keep aspect ratio (or, at least, reduce height)

I'm not sure if I must change it using markdown parameters, change something in *plot_grid()* or the plot area, or in the graphs themselves.

Thanks! :)

NOTE: Data is really irrelevant for this case. If needed, I add my code :)

```
values1.graph <-ggplot(data = values1.df) +
 geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = values1, y = after_stat(density)), fill="steelblue", colour="black", binwidth = 1) +
 ggtitle("Hist .vs. Norm 1") +
 stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = with(values1.df, c(mean = mean(values1), sd = sd(values1))))

values2.graph<-ggplot(data = values2.df) +
 geom_histogram(mapping = aes(x = values2, y = after_stat(density)), fill="steelblue", colour="black", binwidth = 1) +
 ggtitle("Hist .vs. Norm 2") +
 stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = with(values2.df, c(mean = mean(values2), sd = sd(values2))))

plot_grid(values1.graph, values2.graph, labels = NULL)
```

The resulting graph is:
[image]

But, what I want are the graphs with the original aspect ratio, as it shows when I plot them individually:

[image]

I know the graphs will be smaller when keeping the aspect ratio, but i don't mind it. What I don't want is to show a leptokurtic distribution when it is not.

Comment: Could you please share some code you have tried with reproducible data using `dput`?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, what I found is that you can SET the size in Markdown with *fig.width* and *fig.height*, or *out.width* and *out.height*

```
{r Graphs, echo=FALSE, fig.width=14, fig.height=5}
```